# How to get only file names from sharepoint using any API's and c#

Tags: sharepoint-api

I am trying to get only existing file names list with respected date and time from SharePoint using any API and C#.

I am able to download and upload files from SharePoint using webclient, but i am not able to get only file names list with respected date and time to datagridview. Please let me know if there is any solution for that.

I am developing in windows forms application using visual studio environment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please try the c# code below to get the information about the files in directory

```
class FileSysInfo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Get the files in the directory and prints out filename, Last access time and length

        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");


        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code is for getting information about files which are in local drive ex: (@"C:\").

Comment: I wanted to get the information for files from  " SharePoint "

Comment: @Sudhakar Please try using the cpde belowprivate ClientContext _clientContext;
 var oList = _clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SERVERURL);
 var oQuery = new CamlQuery();
 var fileList = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
_clientContext.Load(fileList);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();